# Trying to install pyInstaller, however when creating a venv comes up with error saying "The system cannot find the path specified."

Tags: python, pyinstaller, python-venv

I am trying to install pyInstaller. When I put `-c -i pyi-env-name` into pipWin and click run, it opens a new command box but comes up with the error:

```
The system cannot find the path specified.
1
The system cannot find the path specified.
```

That is all that it writes. Any help solving this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the Scripts subfolder from the python installation folder to the environment variables:

In my case the path is:

```
C:\Users\Costin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Scripts
```

To add the directory to the path in Windows:

```
Edit System Environment Variables -> Environment Variables -> Path -> Edit and paste the path
```

Comment: Nope, sorry, I've added it to the path in windows and it still hasn't worked- any other ideas?